# How to access a collection from inside a "each" block in handlebars.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm trying to do like:

```
{{# each items }}
    {{ @index }} / {{ items.length }}
{{/ each }}
```

but it seems that I can't access `items` inside the `each` block.

Is there any solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use construct:

```
{{# each items }}
    {{ @index }} / {{ ../items.length }}
{{/ each }}
```